# parsing xml tags in a specific order in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to load some tags with a specified order from an xml file into python as below:

```
<data>
    <testset name="ts1" order="1" descrption="this is ts1 descrption">
        <testcase name="tc1" order="1" />
        <testcase name="tc2" order="2" />
    </testset>

    <testset name="ts2" order="2" descrption="this is ts2 descrption">
        <testcase name="tc3" order="1" />
        <testcase name="tc4" order="2" />
    </testset>
</data>
```

The way that I know is ugly so please let me know if there is a better way:

```
class TS():
    def __init__(self, name, order):
        self.name = name
        self.order = order

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def parseXML():
    ts_arr = []
    tree = ET.parse('test_specs.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for testset in root.iter('testset'):
        i = 0
        while i<len(ts_arr):
            if testset.get('order')<ts_arr[i].order:
                        ts_arr.append(i, TS(testset.get('name'),testset.get('order')))
                        break
            i += 1
```

... and the same for testcases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the test sets by their order attribute:

```
root = tree.getroot()
testsets = root.findall('testset')

for testset in sorted(testsets, key=lambda ts: int(ts.attrib['order'])):
    # test sets are looped over in the order specified in the `order` attributes
    testcases = testset.findall('testcase')
    for testcase in sorted(testcases, key=lambda ts: int(ts.attrib['order'])):
        # test cases are looped over in the order specified
```

Comment: Wonderful. 100% bang on. Thanks.